# Why is the orthognal complment of $W_1 + W_2$ equal to the intersection of the orthogonal complement of $W_1$ with the orthogonal complement of $W_2$?

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products

Suppose that $W_1, W_2$ are subspaces of $V$. Show that

$$(W_1 + W_2)^⊥ = W_1^⊥ ∩ W_2^⊥.$$

Comment: Welcome to MSE! What have you tried to tackle the question?

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net  nothing at all, how about give me some hint to how to start to question. Like what are some of the defintion or theory I can use to solve this question?

Comment: Can you start be saying what the orthogonal of a subspace is?

Comment: The superscript $\perp$ doesn’t mean “orthogonal projection.” It means “orthogonal complement.”

Answer (score 0):

By definition,
$$
\left( W_1+W_2 \right)^\perp =  \left\{ \  x \in V \ \colon \  \langle x, v \rangle = 0 \mbox{ for all } v \in W_1 + W_2 \ \right\}
 $$

As $W_1 \subset W_1 + W_2$ and $W_2 \subset W_1 + W_2$, so we can also conclude that any $x \in \left( W_1 + W_2 \right)^\perp$ also is in $W_1^\perp \cap W_2^\perp$, and so
$$ \left( W_1 + W_2 \right)^\perp \subset W_1^\perp \cap W_2^\perp. \tag{1} $$

Now let $x \in W_1^\perp \cap W_2^\perp$. Then $x \in W_1^\perp$ and $x \in W_2^\perp$. Therefore
$$ \left\langle x, w_1 \right\rangle = 0 \ \mbox{ for all } w_1 \in W_1 $$
and 
$$ \left\langle x, w_2 \right\rangle = 0 \ \mbox{ for all } w_2 \in W_2. $$
So for any element $v \in W_1 + W_2$, we have 
$$ v = w_1 + w_2 $$
for some $w_1 \in W_1$ and $w_2 \in W_2$. Therefore
$$
\begin{align}
\langle x, v \rangle &= \left\langle x, w_1 + w_2 \right\rangle \\
&= \left\langle x, w_1  \right\rangle  + \left\langle x, w_2 \right\rangle  \\
&= 0 + 0 \\
&= 0,
\end{align}
$$
thus showing that $x \in \left( W_1 + W_2 \right)^\perp$. Thus
$$ W_1^\perp \cap W_2^\perp \subset \left( W_1 + W_2 \right)^\perp. \tag{2} $$

From (1) and (2) above, we obtain
$$ \left( W_1 + W_2 \right)^\perp = W_1^\perp \cap W_2^\perp. $$

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Hints.

1. If $U_1$ and $U_2$ are subspaces with $U_1\subseteq U_2$, then $U_1^\perp\supseteq U_2^\perp$
2. As a consequence, $(W_1+W_2)^\perp\subseteq W_1^\perp\cap W_2^\perp$.
3. Now prove that $W_1^\perp\cap W_2^\perp\subseteq(W_1+W_2)^\perp$; what are the elements of $W_1+W_2$?